# invalid csrf token when testing a symfony2 form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, testing, csrf

I'm writing a functional test for a symfony2 [2.7.1] website.
The test fills one form, submits it (thus creating an entity), next it follows a link to a second form where it tries to create another entity (related to the first one).

When trying to submit the second form, I get the invalid csrf token error.

Does anyone know what is happening??

I forgot the code! [facepalm]

note that I changed the strings of the buttons and in the assertions because originally they were in Hebrew.

Also, the error occurs also when I render the forms automatically (twig: form(form))

```
public function testCompleteScenario()
{
    // create a customer
    $client = $this->getAdminClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/customer/new');
    $this->assertGreaterThan(
        0,
        $crawler->filter('html:contains("create new customer")')->count(),
        "Failed to get to the create customer form"
    );
    $customerForm = $crawler->selectButton('save')->form();
    $customerForm['crm_customer[name]'] = 'test_customer' . rand(1000, 99999);
    $client->submit($customerForm);
    $crawler = $client->followRedirect();
    $this->assertGreaterThan(
        0,
        $crawler->filter('html:contains("Customer created successfully")')->count(),
        "Failed to create a customer"
    );


    $this->assertGreaterThan(
        0,
        $crawler->filter('html:contains("create new contact")')->count()
    );

    // click the "add new contact" button
    $createContactBtn = $crawler
        ->filter('a:contains("create new contact")')
        ->eq(0)
        ->link()
    ;
    $crawler = $client->click($createContactBtn);

    $this->assertGreaterThan(
        0,
        $crawler->filter('button:contains("save")')->count()
    );

    // create the contact
    $contactForm = $crawler->selectButton('save')->form();
    $contactForm['crm_corebundle_contact[firstName]'] = 'test_contact' . rand(1000, 99999);
    $contactForm['crm_corebundle_contact[lastName]'] = 'lastName';
    $client->submit($contactForm);
    $crawler = $client->followRedirect();
    $this->assertGreaterThan(
        0,
        $crawler->filter('html:contains("contact created successfully")')->count(),
        "Failed to create the contact"
    );
}
```

Comment: How can we know what is wrong without any code.

Comment: How are you rendering the form?

Comment: @RaphaëlMalié: true. I forgot to post it.
I added the code of the test. The form types and the form templates are very basic and standard (generated with the generator bundle).

Comment: @DavidPatterson: The form is rendered with twig, using the most basic function (form(form))